# Pull RSS Feeds From Facebook Page

Tags: c#, facebook, rss, syndicationfeed

I need help to pull RSS feeds from a facebook page I'm using the following code but it keeps giving me an error :

```
string url = 
    "https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=40796308305&format=rss20";

XmlReaderSettings settings = 
    new XmlReaderSettings
                    {
                         XmlResolver = null,
                         DtdProcessing=DtdProcessing.Parse,

                     }; 
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url,settings);

SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

foreach (var item in feed.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Title.Text);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Summary.Text);

}

if (reader != null) reader.Close();
```

This code works perfectly with any blog or page rss but with Facebook rss it give an exception with the following message

> The element with name 'html' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' is not an allowed feed format.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Facebook will return HTML in this instance because it doesn't like the User Agent supplied by XmlReader. Since you can't customize it, you will need a different solution to grab the feed. This should solve your problem:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "GET";
req.UserAgent = "Fiddler";

var rep = req.GetResponse();
var reader = XmlReader.Create(rep.GetResponseStream());

SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
```

This is strictly a behavior of Facebook, but the proposed change should work equally well for other sites that are okay with your current implementation.

Comment: Consider setting your User Agent to the one used by FireFox or Chrome

Comment: Thanks Gregory,Kurru for your answers.I tried both solutions but now I get a different exception which is "'Element' is an invalid XmlNodeType".I think facebook's feeds' format can not be parsed using syndicationFeed class @ least for now.

Comment: At which point (which line) does the exception occur? I think we can track this one down with a little more work.

Comment: I tried this and got the exact same exception... I checked the source of the feed and the offending line is `<access:restriction relationship="deny" xmlns:access="http://www.bloglines.com/about/specs/fac-1.0" />`

Answer (score 2):

It works when using Gregorys code above if you change the feed format to atom10 instead of rss20. 
Change the url:

```
string url = 
"https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=40796308305&format=atom10";
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case also Facebook feed was difficult to consume and then I try with feedburner to burn the feed for my facebook page. Feedburner generated the feed for me in Atom1.0 format. And then I successfully :) consumed this with system.syndication class my code was:

```
string  Main()
   {
       var url = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/Per.........all";


       Atom10FeedFormatter formatter = new Atom10FeedFormatter();
       using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url))
       {
           formatter.ReadFrom(reader);
       }
       var s = "";
       foreach (SyndicationItem item in formatter.Feed.Items)
       {
           s+=String.Format("[{0}][{1}] {2}", item.PublishDate, item.Title.Text, ((TextSyndicationContent)item.Content).Text);
       }

       return s;
   }
```